# WYGWAM taking styles from website css file?

Tags: wygwam, pixelandtonic

Does anyone know why or have ever experienced WYGWAM taking styles from their css file? I recently moved EE from one server to another and on the new server the WYGWAM entry field is taking styles from my css. Can anyone offer any help to why this is happening and how to fix it? (See attached image for better explanation)

[image: WYGWAM Screen Dump]

[image: WYGWAM Editor Settings]

[image: Source from CP]

[image: Screen grab from Safari inspector]

Thanks.
Stephen.

Comment: Hey Stephen - what version of EE and Wygwam are you using? And are you using?  And are you using any Overrides or extensions/accessories that modify the CP?

Comment: Hi Lisa, I'm using EE 2.5.5 and WYGWAM 2.7. I'm using Freebie but not sure that modifies the CP. The add-ons I am using are: WYGWAM, Structure, Simple Math, SEO Lite, Matrix, Low Yearly Variables, Freeform, Freebie and Assets. The only new one on there that wasn't on dev is Reelocate - used to change paths automatically after server move. Thanks.

Comment: If you look in the dev console, do you see the CP calling your CSS?  Also, can you post a screenshot of your Wygwam module settings? Thank you!

Comment: Updated my original post with more images. The CP only calls my css in one place, near the very end of the document, screen grab attached but not sure how legible it is .... thanks.

Comment: I was unclear about what page I needed -I removed the image with the license key in it.  Looking more now. :)

Comment: I am curious - if you remove the reference to your custom CSS File - does that change this issue at all?

Comment: Thanks. I'll update to show where the style is being pulled from if that helps.

Comment: Did you try without your custom CSS reference as a quick test? If that doesn't do it, I may need to get some Superadmin details to look around. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Hi Lisa, I tried to delete the node in the inspector but it didn't make any difference. I can give you a super admin login yes, I have no issue with that. Shall I email that to you? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, when I take the reference to my css file out of the "CSS File" field in the cms the styling issue is no longer there. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Stephen, in that case I'd recommend a dedicated stylesheet for your Wygwam specific style overrides; rather than pointing to your main CSS file (if I'm understanding correctly).  Make sense?

Comment: Hi Lisa, yes, this makes sense, I didn't realise this was a feature of WYGWAM, every day is a school day! I will make a specific style for WYGWAM. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an intentional feature of Wygwam to style the content using your website CSS so when editing it can look exactly like the live content will. At least that's how I always set it up.

I've find the best method for this is:

1. Point it to your default CSS file but also supply so Wygwam-only overrides to tweak how it looks in the editor window (e.g. I often add padding to text doesn't hit the left side of the box) or,
2. Provide it with a special Wygwam only stylesheet that is a simpler modified version of your default styles.

Comment: Hi Benek, thanks for the response. I didn't realise that you could style the WYGWAM field, I will make a WYGWAM specific stylesheet that isn't 100% like my site but takes in the suggestions you have offered. Thanks again.